# have you ever question + past simple in the answer

Tags: grammar, tense, past-tense

> Have you ever been to Japan?
>
> Yes, I went there 5 years ago.

Is it correct to use the past simple to answer, as it refers to something happened in the past and finished?
Or should I answer "Yes, I have been there 5 years ago"? Is there any difference?

Comment: There has to be the past simple there. Your variant is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to the question

> Have you ever been to Japan?

You can simply answer:

> Yes, I **went** there 5 years ago.
>   Yes, I **was** there 5 years ago.
>   Yes, I **had gone** there before going to Australia.

Your proposed answer

> Yes, I **have been** there 5 years ago.

is not used, rather one would say

> Yes, I **have been** there.  I was there 5 years ago.